# Sorting sections issue in NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, swift, chat, nsfetchedresultscontroller, xcode7.3

I'm doing a chat app, where I'm storing chat time for each chat, now I need to display latest chats first, grouped in section, for eg: If I have 10 chats of today it should be under section named July 10, 2016 with last send chat at last. For this I'm sorting the list by chatTimestamp and I have another sectionDate field which stores the corresponding date. Below is a sample format of data that displays in core data.

```
<MyChat.ChatData: 0x7f8b71cdd190> (entity: ChatData; id: 0xd000000000140002 <x-coredata:….> ; data: {
    chatDeviceType = ipad;
    chatId = 3557;
    chatOwnerName = “John Mathew”;
    chatReadStatus = 1;
    chatStatus = Received;
    chatText = “Hi how are you?“;
    chatTimestamp = "2015-09-21 10:41:37 +0000";
    chatType = Mine;
    imageData = nil;
    imageUrl = nil;
    sectionDate = "Sep 21, 2015";
    users = "0xd000000000080000 <x-coredata:…>”;
})
```

This is a portion of my code so far

```
var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController()

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
       setupFRC(limit: LIMIT)
      ......
}


 func setupFRC(limit limit:Int) {

        messageMaxLimit += limit

        let objectsCount = self.stack.mainContext.countForFetchRequest(fetchRequest(self.stack.mainContext), error: nil)

        NSFetchedResultsController.deleteCacheWithName("Root")
        let request = self.fetchRequest(self.stack.mainContext)

        self.fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: request,
                                                                   managedObjectContext: self.stack.mainContext,
                                                                   sectionNameKeyPath: "sectionDate",
                                                                   cacheName: "Root")

        self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = self

        self.messageMaxLimit = self.messageMaxLimit > objectsCount ? objectsCount : self.messageMaxLimit

        if objectsCount > self.messageMaxLimit
        {
            self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.fetchOffset = objectsCount - self.messageMaxLimit
        }

        self.fetchData()

    }

    //To fetch data in FRC
    func fetchData() {

        do {
            try self.fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
            chatCollectionView.reloadData()
        } catch {
            assertionFailure("Failed to fetch: \(error)")
        }
    }


 func fetchRequest(context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> FetchRequest<ChatData> {
        let e = entity(name: "ChatData", context: context)
        let fetch = FetchRequest<ChatData>(entity: e)

        fetch.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "(SELF.users == %@)", currentUser!)
        //Sort by chatTimeStamp
        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "chatTimestamp", ascending: true)
        fetch.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
        return fetch
    }




func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {

        do {
            try self.fetchedResultsController.performFetch()

        } catch {
            assertionFailure("Failed to fetch: \(error)")
        }

        chatCollectionView.reloadData()

    }
```

Now the problem is that the chats seems to have order correctly, but the sections are in alphabetic order. But If I enter a chat and send it and when it reloads from ***controllerDidChangeContent*** it gets corrected.
I can't figure out why it doesn't load in correct order initially.I'm using a collection view for this. Am I doing anything wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by removing the NSManaged attribute for sectionDate and added it like below and made the property transient in the core data model and it worked.

```
var sectionDate: String {
        get {
            self.willAccessValueForKey("sectionDate")
            var ddtmp  = self.primitiveValueForKey("sectionDate") as! String?
            self.didAccessValueForKey("sectionDate")

            if (ddtmp == nil)
            {
                ddtmp = Utilities.stringFromDate(self.chatTimestamp!, dateFormat: "MMM dd, yyyy")
                self.setPrimitiveValue(ddtmp, forKey: "sectionDate")

            }


            return ddtmp!
        }

    }
```